# Derive bound on zeros mod p from effective Chebotarev density theorem

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I'm trying to understand an equation occurring in the proof of Lemma 3 in [Adleman and Odlyzko's *Irreducibility Testing and Factorization of Polynomials*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2007706?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents):

Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$, let $D = |\text{disc } f|$ be the absolute value of its discriminant and let $W(p) = |\{x \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \mid f(x) = 0\}|$ for any positive prime $p \in \mathbb{N}$. Set
\begin{equation}
S(x) = \sum_{\substack{0 \leq p \leq x \\ p \text{ prime} \\ p \not| D}} (1 - W(p)),
\end{equation}
for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
I'd like to understand how to prove the asymptotic bound
\begin{equation}
|S(x)| = O(\sqrt{x} \log(Dx^n)),
\end{equation}
which is the second equation (without number) in the proof of the abovementioned lemma.
The proof says that this follows from the effective Chebotarev density theorem (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev%27s_density_theorem#Effective_Version)) "since the discriminant of the field generated by a root of $f(x)$ is bounded in absolute value by $D$".

I don't understand what's going on here. What is the extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ we're considering? The field generated by a root of $f$ will in general not be Galois, so it seems to me that the splitting field of $f$ will be involved, but its discriminant is not bounded by $D$. The example given by Jingwei Xue in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8312/discriminant-of-a-monic-irreducible-integer-polynomial-vs-discriminant-of-its-s) suggests to me that it will not even be polynomial in $D$ in the worst case.

But even if this obstacle can be overcome, I don't know wich conjugacy class of the Galois group to look at. Maybe the trivial one containing only the identity, because it corresponds to primes that split completely?